# Hauppauge HVR-950Q - Linux - Over-the-air broadcasts

Tags: linux, tv, gentoo, hauppauge

I am using a Hauppauge HVR-950Q and have the device installed and setup in Linux.  I cannot however watch over-the-air broadcasts.  If I reboot to Windows, I can watch tv (about 15 - 20 stations).

I am using tvtime and get 'No Signal'.  The device node /dev/video0 is created, what else am I missing?

Thanks,

Walter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i did not check. but maybe your card produces a mpeg stream in some way?

i once had a digital pvr card after owning an analog bt878 card and it took me some time to
get it running. in the end it was about the correct modules loading and setting up vlc to
pick up the mpeg stream from the correct device.

using tvtime was not possible anymore. that was quite a setback with this change from analog to digital, because i liked tvtime a lot.

good luck.

regards,

Martin

Comment: Martin, thanks for your reply - How do I change channels then?

Comment: No, my device doesn't encode mpeg streams.

Comment: I ended up using mplayer, it does indeed output an mpeg2 video stream.